# General approach for creating a Yelp-like app for Android OS

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-api

I want to create an app on the lines of a restaurant discovery app such as Yelp or Urbanspoon that detects my current location using GPS co-ordinates and once that is retrieved it finds different services such as Hotels, ATMs etc that is near me (say at a distance of 5 miles radius from my current location). I understand that this could be done using two APIs offered by Google; Google Maps and Google Places so I'm plan to use these two APIs for my project.

As such I would like to get to know a general strategy or an approach that I should follow for initiating the development of my project, (eg. which API should be used where etc.). Could anyone suggest me a step-by-step plan or a framework that I should follow for making such an app? Thanks.

Comment: THis question is way too broad for stack overflow.  If you're asking for the "general approach" for a program it probably isn't on topic here unless the program is dead trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You should...

1) use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to grab user position

2) search using [Google Places API for Android's near by search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) function to get a list of your results.

3) place the result back on the map using [Google Maps Android API v2's marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)